# How to use netInfo in a right way

Tags: react-native

I've used NetInfo to check the internet connection. It works fine but since I've to fetch the json data as soon as the app opens, I've used it in componentDidMount or componentWillMount method. What happens is that if there is no connection at the start, it detects otherwise it doesn't. How can I use it as facebook and youtube does? In those apps, as soon as the internet is not available, it detects and shows no connection and when it is available, it automatically works. Where should I use netInfo to achieve this functionality?

```
componentDidMount() {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
      this.setState({
        isConnected: isConnected
      });
      if (isConnected) {
        fetch(baseUrl)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ __ _ _ 
            _ _ _ _ __ _ _ _ __ _ _ 
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `event listener`. Attach a handler with `connectionChange` event so that app will know when there is a change in the connection.

```
NetInfo.addEventListener(
  'connectionChange',
  changeHandler
);
```

In handler function detect the status and act accordingly

```
var changeHandler = (connectionInfo) => {
  // use connectionInfo.type to determine the status
}
```

Take a look at the [document](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/0.52/netinfo#addeventlistener).

Hope this will help!

Comment: hi, I cannot make it work. The code inside handleConnectionChange doesn't work. I used this.handleConnectionChange(), then it gives undefined in log. Otherwise nothing is in the log. snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/networkcheck

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with `snack.expo.io`.

Comment: It worked finally. You see in your example above, the parameters of addEventListener are in the next line. If you adjust them in single line  "NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange)", they worked. I don't know why that happened? Its absurd.

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use it at the top level of the APP.Like in App.js or whatever the root component you have.

You can register a listener like this:

```
NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
  'connectionChange',
  this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
);
```

So whenever the network status changes it will call the `handleFirstConnectivityChange` function.And you can define you function as

```
handleFirstConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
    if(isConnected) {
        //Network status is online
        // Display any toast or message
    } else {
        // Network status is offline
        // Display any toast or message
    }
     console.log(isConnected, 'isConnected');
}
```

Comment: I cannot make it work. The code inside handleConnectionChange doesn't work. I I use this.handleConnectionChange(), then it gives undefined in log. Otherwise nothing is in the log.  https://snack.expo.io/@codebyte99/networkcheck

Comment: Snack expo architecture I am not sure.When we disconnect, the server is not able to send the response to us(console.log in this case).If you run locally it gets called.But what I found is it is not that reliable.Many times it does not gets called.

Comment: I have created react-native project where it doesn't work as well. That's why I've created an expo project to show you the codes.

Comment: It worked finally. You see in your example above, the parameters of addEventListener are in the next line. If you adjust them in single line  "NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', this.handleConnectionChange)", they worked. I don't know why that happened?